How can I reverse the polarity of a DC model train (12 V) using MOSFETs instead of relays?
At this moment I reverse the polarity of the traction voltage  of my 12 V analog model railroad (older Fleischmann models) by using relays, driven by an Arduino microcontroller. However, I want to replace the relay stuff by an electronic device which can do this for me without drop voltage over the contacts. The electronic device should be optically isolated from the traction voltage supply and suitable of being controlled by TTL level control signals. I figure a design with MOSFETs could be the best solution.

Just go DCC and save yourself all the build hassle.

Do not expect FETs to drop less voltage than relay contacts.

Going DCC is not possible. The older Fleischmann locs that I own require isolated motor shields for conversion to digital locs, and those shields are obsolete. So I have to stay on analog operation.

H-Bridge is the term you need to search for.

Look at H-bridges

Driving MOSFETs from logic signals has a few traps for the unwary as do H-bridges. Using DPDT relays to reverse your locos is a practical solution.

Why do you think there is a significant voltage drop across the relay contacts?  Have you measured it?  Have you measured the closed relay contacts resistance?  Without these numbers, an informed decision cannot be made.

Voltage drop accros relay contacts: I noticed slowing down of train speed and measured voltage drop of 1 to 2 volts over the closed relay contact in use at that moment. Also detoriation of relay contact -worsening the voltage drop over time- is a reason for me to consider the use of a pure electronic voltage reverser.

As mentioned in comments, the contact resistance of a relay is generally quite small. There is overhead to using relays in terms of the coil current, and perhaps that is what you were concerned about.
Anyway, if you want to have bidirectional drive using MOSFETs, the way to do that is with an H-bridge.
The "guts" of an H-bridge consists of 4 MOSFETs arranged like so

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The operating principle is to never have two transistors on the same side (left or right) on at the same time. Thus, the legal states would be

M1 and M4 on, all others off
M2 and M3 on, all others off
All MOSFETs off

Although the "guts" of an H-bridge consists of 4 (electronic) switches, an actual implementation requires driving circuitry to control the gates of the MOSFETs.
There are off-the-shelf populated PCBs for Arduino that implement both the H-bridge and the driver circuitry. It is probably easiest to go with one of these. But if you want the satisfaction of doing it yourself, one of these boards can give you a model to work from.
You mention that you want opto-isolation. That can be achieved with a second board, if you decide to go with a prebuilt H-bridge and driver. There are many schematics on-line for opto-isolating the outputs of an Arduino.
